# iOS set google map default camera position

Tags: ios, google-maps

Setting the default camera position for google maps can easily be set in [Android xml](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#configure_initial_state) so that the map camera will start at that location instead of the Atlantic ocean.

I am initially doing this on the viewWillAppear

```
mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: getDefaultLocation(), zoom: 10, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
```

It seems to work fine but I am unable to find any documentation on the way to do this for iOS like in Android.  Anyone know of a way to do similar in iOS like that of Android or is what I'm doing the best way of doing it?

The getDefaultLocation() function just creates a CLLocationCoordinate2D with the default coordinates.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the position from the xib?

Comment: If something like that is even available it would great but I didn't find anything; or if what I'm doing is what is to be done.

Comment: I don't think that's possible; you'll have to do it the way you are currently doing it.